# Add data from one table to another when data in two other specific fields are identical

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I'm working on populating a cadastral table with codes from a database that comprises historic information about farms. Since both tables contain thousands of rows I'm looking for ways to automate the process. The two tables don't always have a direct correlation but there are ways to update the cadastral table automatically.

The database is PostgreSQL 9.4

The relevant fields in table 1 are:

```
county_name 
farm_name 
new_field_for_fk
```

For the second:

```
county_name 
farm_name 
pk
```

Neither the `county_name` nor the `farm_name` are unique identifiers, but for 99% of the time the combination of the two is, and I want to update `new_field_for_fk` with the data in `pk` where `county_name` **and** `farm_name` are identical. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try an `UPDATE` with a `FROM` clause, from your description of the problem.

Something like:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET new_field_for_fk = t2.pk 
FROM table2 t2 
WHERE t1.county_name = t2.county_name 
  AND t1.farm_name = t2.farm_name ;
```

Should update all rows based on the matching of the two keys across the tables.